# Xcode won't step into class constructor

Tags: c++, xcode

We are trying to debug a problem in c++. Unfortunately the problem seems to happen in the constructor of a class. When we try to step into the constructor Xcode steps over it instead. Does anyone know why Xcode has this behavior?

Comment: It can be you have problem in initialization list of your constructor, which is executed prior to the body...

Comment: That could be indeed an exception there would not continue the code, alas, our class is as empty as it can be, and still I don't get into the constructor(the not empty part)

Comment: Is the class inherited from any other class? (base constructors will be called first). If not can you provide small sample of relevant code on how constructor is actually called?

Comment: No, the class is as simple as it can get, indeed some code could help:   `class A { public: A() { std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl; } }; int main() { A* a = new A(); delete a; }`  The only weird thing is that A is defined in a library and not in the project that contains main

Comment: I see the same thing with swift classes (in Version 11.2.1 (11B500) (circa Dec 2019). You would think that stepping into swift constructor should stop in the constructor without setting a breakpoint in it. Once long ago I remember it stopping inside the constructor: 
class A { var prop = 2; init() { prop = 3 } }
let anA = A()  /// Put break here, and try to single step INTO A() constructor. It steps OVER it

Answer (score 0):

If you put a breakpoint inside that constructor, that should take care of it. Unless the constructor is not actually being called.